# Jenkins conditional steps token logic operators

Tags: jenkins, conditional-statements, boolean-operations

I inject environmental variable from a file myprop.property that has the contents:

> var1=y 
>   var2=y

**The build steps:**
 1. Inject environment variables:

> Property File  Path:${JENKINS_HOME}/myprop.propertie

2. Execute Windows batch command (to verify variable injected successully)

> echo var1 = %var1% 
>  echo var2 = %var2%

3. Condition steps (multiple)

> Run?: Boolean condition
>  
>   Token: ${ENV,var="var1"}||${ENV,var="var2"} 
>   Steps to run if condition is met: echo Yes, works!

Run the build, the condition in step 3 never met while step 2 display the correct values of the variables.
I have tried the conditions and operators:

> var1=y, var2=y: ${ENV,var="var1"}||${ENV,var="var2"}
>   var1=y, var2=y: ${ENV,var="var1"}|${ENV,var="var2"}
>
> var1=y, var2=n: ${ENV,var="var1"}||${ENV,var="var2"}
>   var1=y, var2=n: ${ENV,var="var1"}|${ENV,var="var2"}

Uppercase or lower case of the values do not make any difference. I am running jenkins 1.641 on windows 7 pro.
**If I use only one e.g. ${ENV,var="var1"} in the token field, it works as expected.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, change step 3 to:

> Run?: Or 
>   Boolean condition
>   Token: ${ENV,var="var1"}
>   Or
>   Boolean condition
>   Token: ${ENV,var="var2"}
>   **Never**

these are actually three conditions. the execution asserts the first condition first, if it's met, stop checking; if not met, asserts the second; and so on until the last condition that is **Never**, meaning if no condition is met, stop executing the step.

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead, It worked for me, we need to mention Boolean Condition with Token mentioned in the image.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the form input fields in your answer to allow copy and paste, and explain why this might be a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

I see my post attracted lots interests. Here are what I eventually worked around.

Use **Regular expression match** seems to be more readable than using **Boolean Condition**.

If the logic is an "**OR**",

```
? = Regular expression match
expression = ${ENV,var="var1"}|${ENV,var="var2"}
Label = Y
```

Note that the logic operator is a **single '|'**, **not double '||'**.

if the logic is an **"AND"**,

```
? = Regular expression match
expression = ${ENV,var="var1"}${ENV,var="var2"}
Label = YY
```

The `expression` is just concatenation of the two variables, and the `Label` is so as well.